# How to upload contacts from mobile application using API?

Tags: rest-api, contact, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, import

I would like to export the contacts to salesforce from my own mobile application. Is there any API for exporting the contacts to salesforce?

Can I do this via mobile application? Or else do I need to do this via PHP application?

Answer (score 0):

1.First, you take backup of your contact from Mobile to CSV file.
2.Click on 'Contacts' after being logged to your Salesforce account.
3.Select 'Import My Accounts & Contacts' for the import process to start.
4.Click on the 'Start the Import Process' for the process to begin.
5.Click on the source from where the contacts are to be imported.
6.Click on 'Accept' for import completion.

Comment: I need an API to communicate with the salesforce to export the contacts. I  cant do manual. I am developing a mobile application where I can export the contact using API directly from my applications.